# PHP: list files on ftp server?

Tags: php, ftp, connection

can't get it done!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>FTP Download</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php

    set_time_limit(300);//for setting 
    $path='/userupload';
    $ftp_server='202. …';
    $ftp_server_port="21";
    $ftp_user_name='al…';
    $ftp_user_pass="mypassword";

    // set up a connection to ftp server
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_server_port); 
    // login with username and password
    $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

    // check connection and login result
    if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
        echo "Fail</br>";
    } else {
        echo "Success</br>";
        // enabling passive mode
        ftp_pasv( $conn_id, true );
        // get contents of the current directory
        $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path);
        // output $contents
        var_dump($contents);
    }

    // close the FTP connection
    ftp_close($conn_id);

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

any idea what I'm doing wrong? it always returns "Success bool(false)"! So the connection is working, however the files won't get listed. Any ideas?

regards

Answer (score 0):

> what I'm doing wrong?

you've lack of debugging.

checking only connect result is not enough. have to check every operation as well.

did ftp_pasv() worked?
is there /userupload dir?

Comment: did ftp_pasv() work? -> I have no idea!
is there a /userupload dir? -> sure, there is!

Comment: @mathiregister you misunderstood. You don't have to answer these questions here. you have to write code that checks every operation result. and find the point where things goes wrong

Comment: @mathiregister the same way as previous statements. every function has return value that can be checked

Comment: i have no chance to find the bug! i would be really grateful if you could help me out.

Answer (score 0):

what Shrapnel is saying is you can have more debugging than youve got if you've got

`//enabling passive mode
ftp_pasv( $conn_id, true );`

then you can use `if(ftp_pasv( $conn_id, true )){// it worked :) }else{// it didnt work :( }`

But what I think is wrong is your path, if the home folder of your ftp user lands them inside here /useruploads/*im here* then to list the files your path should be  `$path='/';` otherwise what your telling the ftp to do is list the directory "useruploads/useruploads" which isnt going to exist.